# SQL To determine if today is a bank holiday

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

so i have a web page that asks the user to input there timesheets into the full monthly data, but what i am trying to do is automatically input to the timesheet that there is a public holiday on this date... Can anybody help..

P.s i have a table with the stored holidays in there so i need to match todays date and if on that day it is a holiday then the box should show 'HH' sql . this is part of a large sql stored proc.. but i believe the implementation is to happen here....

```
DECLARE @DaysInMonth INT

    SELECT @DaysInMonth = DATEPART(dd, DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, 1, CAST(CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME))))

    DECLARE @Today DATETIME
    DECLARE @LunchStart DATETIME
    DECLARE @LunchEnd DATETIME
    DECLARE @CurrentMonth VARCHAR(16)
    DECLARE @CurrentDay INT
    SELECT @CurrentDay = 1

    SELECT @CurrentMonth = CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR) + '-'

    DECLARE @DailyDataId INT

    WHILE @CurrentDay <= @DaysInMonth
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Today = CONVERT(DATETIME, @CurrentMonth + CAST(@CurrentDay AS VARCHAR),  20)

        -- If it's not a working day don't set a lunchbreak
        IF (DATENAME(weekday, @Today) IN (SELECT WorkingDay FROM dbo.udfGetWorkingDays(@TempTimesheetId)))
        BEGIN
            SELECT @LunchStart = @CurrentMonth + CAST(@CurrentDay AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(hh, @AMOut) AS VARCHAR) + ':' + CAST(DATEPART(mi, @AMOut) AS VARCHAR)
            SELECT @LunchEnd = @CurrentMonth + CAST(@CurrentDay AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(hh, @PMIn) AS VARCHAR) + ':' + CAST(DATEPART(mi, @PMIn) AS VARCHAR)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @LunchStart = NULL
            SELECT @LunchEnd = NULL
        END
```

Comment: happen at the end

Comment: i am new to sql and have been tasked to achieve this with this stored proc

Comment: Bank/public holiday in _which_ country?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen he has a table of them

Comment: Start thinking in *sets*. If you had a calendar table (one row per day) you could *join* that table to another result set or make it the *basis* for writing this query. And it'll surely have column(s) that indicate whether it's a normal workday, holiday, weekend, etc. Try not to write *procedural* code here. (Some people quail at the thought of how *wasteful* a row for every day is, without contemplating that 20 years worth of data is still less than 10000 rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe you dont need a static table for holidays, 
what i currently use is;

btw you can add your local holidays for UK

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_is_it_holiday](@country varchar(3),@date datetime) 
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN 
    declare @Tatilmi bit
    if @country in ('TR','TUR','792')
        select @Tatilmi = case 
            when datepart(dw,@date) in (7,1) then 1--Weekends
            when CONVERT(nchar,@date,131) like ' 2/10/%' then 1 --'Ramadan 1st'
            when CONVERT(nchar,@date,131) like ' 3/10/%' then 1 --'Ramadan 2nd'
            when CONVERT(nchar,@date,131) like ' 4/10/%' then 1 --'Ramadan 3rd'
            when CONVERT(nchar,@date,131) like '10/12/%' then 1 --'Sacrifice 1st'
            when CONVERT(nchar,@date,131) like '11/12/%' then 1 --'Sacrifice 2nd'
            when CONVERT(nchar,@date,131) like '12/12/%' then 1 --'Sacrifice 3nd'
            when CONVERT(nchar,@date,131) like '13/12/%' then 1 --'Sacrifice 4th'
            when CONVERT(varchar,@date, 121) like '____-01-01%' then 1 --'New Year'
            when CONVERT(varchar,@date, 121) like '____-04-23%' then 1 --'Children Day'
            when CONVERT(varchar,@date, 121) like '____-05-19%' then 1 --'Youht and Sports Day'
            when CONVERT(varchar,@date, 121) like '____-08-30%' then 1 --'Victory Day'
            when CONVERT(varchar,@date, 121) like '____-10-29%' then 1 --'Republic Day'
        else 0 end
    else if @country in ('US','USA','840')
        select @Tatilmi = case 
            when datepart(dw,@date) in (7,1) then 1--Weekends
            when CONVERT(varchar,@date, 121) like '____-01-01%' then 1 --'New Year'
            when CONVERT(varchar,@date, 121) like '____-07-04%' then 1 --'Independence'
            when CONVERT(varchar,@date, 121) like '____-11-11%' then 1 --'Veterans'
            when CONVERT(varchar,@date, 121) like '____-12-25%' then 1 --'X-Mas 1st'
            when CONVERT(varchar,@date, 121) like '____-12-26%' then 1 --'X-Mas 2st'
            when CONVERT(varchar,@date, 121) like '____-12-27%' then 1 --'X-Mas 3st'
            when CONVERT(varchar,@date, 121) like '____-12-28%' then 1 --'X-Mas 4th'
            when CONVERT(varchar,@date, 121) like '____-12-29%' then 1 --'X-Mas 5th'
            when CONVERT(varchar,@date, 121) like '____-12-30%' then 1 --'X-Mas 6th'
            when CONVERT(varchar,@date, 121) like '____-12-31%' then 1 --'X-Mas 7th'
            when dbo.fn_nth_weekday_of_month(5,4,10,year(@date))=@date then 1--Thanksgiving 
            when dbo.fn_nth_weekday_of_month(2,3,6,year(@date))=@date then 1--Martin Luther King
            when dbo.fn_nth_weekday_of_month(2,3,2,year(@date))=@date then 1--Birth Day of G.Washington and A.Lincoln
            when dbo.fn_nth_weekday_of_month(2,1,9,year(@date))=@date then 1--Workers
            when dbo.fn_nth_weekday_of_month(2,2,10,year(@date))=@date then 1--colombus
        else 0 end
    RETURN @Tatilmi
END


CREATEFUNCTION [dbo].[fn_nth_weekday_of_month](@Weekday int, @nth int, @month int, @year int) 
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN 
    declare @iteration_date datetime, @i int=0
    set @iteration_date = convert(datetime,convert(varchar(4),@year)+'-'+convert(varchar(2),@month)+'-'+'01 00:00')
    while (year(@iteration_date)=@year)and(month(@iteration_date)=@month)
    begin
        if datepart(weekday,@iteration_date)=@Weekday
            set @i = @i + 1
        if @i = @nth
            break;
        set @iteration_date = dateadd(day,1,@iteration_date)
    end
    return @iteration_date
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `EXISTS` to check whether the day is a holiday, i.e. a record with that day exists in the holiday table.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM <holiday table>
                  WHERE <day column> = @Today)
BEGIN
  -- special handling for holidays goes here
END;
```

Replace `<holiday table>` with the name of your holiday table and `<day column>` with the column in that table, that holds the day.

Comment: It would be _slightly_ more efficient to `Select NULL` rather than `Select *` - there's no need to return data.  And by "slightly" I mean "you'd need a micrometer and an Olympics-grade stopwatch to measure it", but if the code executes a million times a day, it adds up.

Comment: @Brian: When in an `EXISTS` the list of selected columns doesn't matter at all. The engine will ignore it, the expressions are not evaluated and there is no data returned. Try `EXISTS (SELECT 1 / 0)`. You'd expect a "Divide by zero error encountered." error, but you won't get one. `SELECT *` is fine for `EXISTS`.

Comment: @Brian: in the `IF EXISTS()` case - **no data** is returned - so whether you're using `SELECT *` or `SELECT NULL` makes **absolutely NO difference** whatsoever. The only thing returned is an indication of whether (or not) any data that matches the `WHERE` clause exists

Comment: @Brian  - only if you're working on something like, I *think* SQL Server 6.5 or older. Similarly for most other database systems. It's "advice" that was relevant decades ago but it doesn't apply in 2018.